# Ruby Datetime parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, date, datetime

I am trying to compare rows by dates. First, I am saving data with string date's like this:

```
2/10/15 23:37
```

into my PostgreSQL DB.

I can see that my date was saved and now looks like this: `2015-02-10 23:37:00`, and the locale field is set to `lc_collate = en_US.UTF-8`.

Now I am using the same file, and I want to compare the date field, to see if it's the same (and it should be!), but Ruby reads `2/10/15 23:37` as `0002-10-15 13:01:00 +0800`.

I was trying also this:

```
Date.strptime(myDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

But the result was `0015-02-12`.

How can I force Ruby to read my input string the same way as my DB? I was trying to set `config.i18n.default_locale = 'en-US'` in my application.rb but it didn't help.

Comment: Date parsing is one of the highest candidates for "most likely to cause errors" I know. In the U.S., dates typically are MM/DD/YY(YY) format, but the rest of the world works with DD/MM/YY(YY). You have to be very careful not to parse a date either way unless you are very sure where it's coming from. Months can be out of range if what is actually the day value is parsed as a month and is > 12, leading to exceptions. It's worse when the day value is in the month range but then day and month are transposed. There is no way to protect against this problem either, you have to know the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're supplying a two digit year, it should be:

```
Date.strptime(myDate, "%m/%d/%y") # Note the lower case y
```

If the time is also important, you should use:

```
DateTime.strptime(myDate, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

Comment: That was more then helpful! After all I use DateTime.strptime(myDate, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M").to_s(:db)) and my output is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
starting_time = Time.now - 1.hour
starting_time.to_s(:db)
```

This will render the `starting_time` in my example to match what you would find in a database DATETIME field.

Comment: I've got this error now: "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)". I assumed, that it's related with my starting_time being already string type. So to get fast answer, I tried starting_time.to_time.to_s(:db), but I got  0002-11-15 12:54:00 in respond.

Comment: With Time.now i got correct output though - 2015-05-11 21:05:19 +0800.

Comment: So `to_s(:db)` was helpful after all... +1